# What is the best book with american typography rules?

Tags: typography, formatting

There is russian book, [The Publisher’s and Author’s Handbook by Arkady Miltchin and Ludmila Tcheltsova](http://www.artlebedev.com/everything/izdal/spravochnik-izdatelya-i-avtora-2014/) which is well-known and considered the best comprehensive guide to typography and writing of text in Russian (formatting, margins, font sizes and so on). You can get the idea if you peek my link (even though everything is in Russian).

Is there an American alternative available?

Answer (score 1):

[The Elements of Typographical Style](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Elements-Typographic-Style-Robert-Bringhurst/dp/0881792063), by Robert Bringhurst, is a typographical must-read. I'd definitely recommend this!

Comment: I have some specific questions about lists, do you know any authoritative books which describe proper lists formatting and punctuation marks in lists (in formal texts)?